# Libtool - Mismatch version

Tags: centos, automake, libtool, autoreconf

I try to install USBIP on Centos 5.11 (Kernel 2.6.18-409.el5) but I always have this error when I type "make" :

```
make[1]: Entering directory "/root/Downloads/usbip-0.1.7/src"
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory "/root/Downloads/usbip-0.1.7/src/lib"
if /bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..    -Wall -W -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99  -DUSBIDS_FILE='"/usr/local/share/usbip/usb.ids"' -g -O2 -MT libusbip_la-names.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libusbip_la-names.Tpo" -c -o libusbip_la-names.lo "test -f "names.c" || echo './'"names.c; \
        then mv -f ".deps/libusbip_la-names.Tpo" ".deps/libusbip_la-names.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/libusbip_la-names.Tpo"; exit 1; fi   


libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 1.9b, but the
 libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from an older release.
    libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 1.9b
    libtool: and run autoconf again.
    make[2]: [libusbip_la-names.lo] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory "/root/Downloads/usbip-0.1.7/src/lib"
    make[1]: [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory "/root/Downloads/usbip-0.1.7/src"
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I saw several solution on forums, like "autoreconf -vfi" but it does not work for me.

I currently try to reinstall libtool to have the last version but I can't. When I type "yum remove libtool", I'm always able to type "libtool --version" :

```
[tuk@VM01 Downloads]# libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 1.9b
Written by Gordon Matzigkeit <gord@gnu.ai.mit.edu>, 1996

Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And binaries are always here :

```
[tuk@VM01 Downloads]# find / -name "libtool*"
/opt/share/man/man1/libtoolize.1
/opt/share/man/man1/libtool.1
/opt/share/aclocal/libtool.m4
/opt/share/info/libtool.info-1
/opt/share/info/libtool.info-2
/opt/share/info/libtool.info
/opt/share/libtool
/opt/bin/libtool
/opt/bin/libtoolize
/usr/local/share/man/man1/libtoolize.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/libtool.1
/usr/local/share/aclocal/libtool.m4
/usr/local/share/info/libtool.info-1
/usr/local/share/info/libtool.info-2
/usr/local/share/info/libtool.info
/usr/local/share/libtool
/usr/local/bin/libtool
/usr/local/bin/libtoolize
/usr/share/automake-1.9/am/libtool.am
```

Is there any solution fro me to install USBIP ? Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !

I haved several binaries for libtool :

```
[root@SVSLOFLEX2 ~]# which -a libtool
/usr/local/bin/libtool
/usr/bin/libtool
```

The version of /usr/local/bin is the 1.9b (and it don't work)

I added this line to use another version of libtool (by default) :

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

The version of /usr/bin is the 1.5.22, and it work, USBIP is now installed.